# Puppeteer - Map real mobile device behavior in headless (true | false) mode

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I want to emulate a custom device **( real mobile device dimensions)** with a puppeteer, and I expect same browser behavior in real mobile device and puppeteer.
I tried

```
const _op = {
             args: [
                 '--no-sandbox', `--window-size=980,1788`
             ],
             headless: false,
             timeout: 60000,
             ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
             defaultViewport: {
                 height: 1788,
                 width: 980,
                 isMobile: true,
                 hasTouch: true,
                 isLandscape: false,
                 deviceScaleFactor: 3
             }

         }
```

**Problem**
Coordinated (x,y) mismatched in real mobile device and puppeteer, like if it plot (200,300) it shows the different positions in the real mobile device and in puppeteer chromium browser .

**Is these's way to map real mobile device dimensions in puppeteer,** or any suggestions, if I'm missing something ?

Answer (score 1):

The puppeteer `deviceDescriptors` use an object from preset value, you can pass in an object with custom values directly in `page.emulate()`

```
page.emulate({
  "name": "Moto G4",
  "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; Moto G (4)) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4812.0 Mobile Safari/537.36",
  "viewport": {
    "width": 640,
    "height": 360,
    "deviceScaleFactor": 3,
    "isMobile": true,
    "hasTouch": true,
    "isLandscape": false
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To emulate a device on which to load the page you can use `page.emulate(iPhone)` for emulating iphone as in the example:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const iPhone = puppeteer.devices['iPhone 6'];

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.emulate(iPhone);
  await page.goto('https://www.google.com');
  // other actions...
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Maybe this can help you: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#puppeteerdevices

Comment: Hii @Mattia Thanks for your response. Actually, i want to emulate mobile device with custom dimensions,  mobile devices not in **puppeteer DeviceDescriptors**